# How to completely remove the title bar/ window decorations in Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: gnome

Before I start, yes I already know about maximise, pixelsaver and no title bar. The problem is that all of these programs only hide the title bar when the program is maximized while I want the title bars to be gone completely. They are quite essentially useless to me and just a waste of space. I would really appreciate anything on this cause I've looked a lot and haven't found anything that does this.